# jQuery - check if DIV on external page exists, then if it does, load the DIV, otherwise load another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load

working on a custom weather page for a small ops dashboard. `getweather#.php` scrapes the weather information I want, and then index.php loads the specific elements on demand with jQuery.

so - I'm trying to get jQuery to check if specific DIV exists on external page, and if it does, then load it, but if it doesn't, load another DIV that always will exist

based on the other questions I've found here, I put together this code, thinking it would work:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        if ($('getweather2.php?wx=1 #warning').is('*')) {
            $('#wxwarning').load('getweather2.php?wx=1 #warning');
        } else {
            $('#wxwarning').load('getweather2.php?wx=1 #nowarning');
        }
    });
</script>
```

sadly, this does not appear to work, furthermore, it causes all other jQuery functions to fail.

I can't seem to find any examples or anything really to help me get this script to work.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to actually get the data before you can check if elements exists or not.
You can't use `load()`, as it inserts the data directly, but it's just a shortcut for `$.get`, so you can use that instead, and check if the element exists, and if it does insert it, if not insert another element :

```
$.get('getweather2.php?wx=1', function(html) {
    var el = $('<div />').append(html);
    if ( el.find('#warning').length ) {
        $('#wxwarning').html(el.find('#warning'));
    }else{
        $('#wxwarning').html(el.find('#nowarning'));
    }
});
```

Comment: excellent, thank you @adeneo! it works. as a general rule, do you recommend your way of loading all external content? or using the `load()` command?